# Is there a way to use the scipy.interpolate rbf function without compiling?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, cython

I want to use the "rbf" function from scipy.interpolate without installing neither scipy nor cython. First I tried to import only the source code of the rbf-function. But Rbf itselfs want to import other functions among others .pxd-files wherein cython is used, which is also not installed on the maschine the python script is running on. Is there a way to use the 2dinterpolation rbf without compiling scipy?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: No, there is no nice approach (it also needs Fortran). Consider solving the install-problem!

Comment: Look into [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you cannot get a scipy wheel for your platform, nor you can use e.g. Anaconda, you can of course just take https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.18.1/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py#L57-L240
and try to use the code standalone. There will be two issues to solve:

- `scipy.special.xlogy`. This is just `x*log(y)` with special care taken so
  that it's equal zero for x=0. Can easily replicate in pure python or numpy if needs be.
- `scipy.linalg.solve`.  If you have numpy, you can replace it with `numpy.linalg.solve`. If you don't have numpy, uhm, well, you've a problem.